# How to copy file and run script based on current date?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Every day after midnight I have to copy log file from day before.

Log names are in format exYYMMDD.log. So today (22.10.2011) I would have to copy file named ex111021.log into some directory.

Is it possible to do it in batch script? If not I could use powershell but would prefer not as it is not installed on my server.

Edit:
With help of Siva Charan I created this (polish win7 - echo %date% prints YYYY-MM-DD)

```
set /a yest_Day = %date:~8,2%-%var:~-2,1%
copy ex%date:~2,2%%date:~5,2%%yest_Day%.log targetDir
```

Comment: yes it is possible. Refer my answer. +1 for using batch script.

Comment: @Peri see http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetimentmath.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In powershell :

```
$YesterdayfileName = [string]::format("{0:yyMMdd}", ((Get-Date).adddays(-1)))+".log
# today 22/20/2011 gives 111021.log

Copy-Item $YesterdayfileName c:\temp
```

Comment: I'll have to go with this solution.

Answer (score 4):

Implement this way in **Batch** file.

### Syntax of Copy Command:

```
copy sourcefilepath destinationfilepath
```

### Example:

***For today's date:***

```
copy ex%date:~12,10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.log D:\
```

***For yesterday's date:***

```
set /a yest_Day = %date:~7,2%-%var:~-2,1%
copy ex%date:~12,10%%date:~4,2%%yest_Day%.log D:\
```

You have to provide proper file path before the file name **ex111022.log** / **ex111021.log** and destination too.

You can make a schedule for this batch file, which will run on daily basis.

Comment: Have you tried it? It doesn't work. It doesn't work for today's date and for yesterday's date set doesn't work. I get error saying No argument (message translated from polish)

Comment: @Peri: After testing on my machine then only I have posted.

Comment: @Peri: Which OS are you using? Your file is saved as ".bat" format?

Comment: Ok for today's date it's  ex%date:~2,2%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%.log on my system. Win7 polish. Based on that %date:~x,y% substrings y characters starting from x character. What echo %date% prints on your system? I see you use substring 12,10 which should substring 10 characters starting at 12th,

Comment: As it turns out it doesn't work. It doesn't work for days before 20th of the month but I managed to fix that. But it also doesn't work for first day of the month. It calculates day = 0.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/do-schedule-automatic-file-copy-t493716.html

Comment: No that's not answer to my question. I have no problem scheduling. I don't know how to create name of the file using yesterday's date in batch file.